# Error when create connection from .netcore 3.1 to Amazon MQ (RabbitMQ)

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq, message-queue, amazon-mq

My code below is in .netcore 3.1 (use RabbitMQ.Client 6.1) to connect to AmazonMQ (RabbitMQ)

```
factory = new ConnectionFactory
{
    HostName = "amqps://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com",
    UserName = "username",
    Password = "password",
    Port = 5671
};        
                
factory.Uri = new Uri(string.Format("{0}:{1}", factory.HostName, factory.Port));         
connection = factory.CreateConnection();
```

I publish the code using self-container and it works well in a machine (Windows 10), however when I run it in a Windows 7, I got this error.

```
[ERR] Could not make connection to RabbitMQ on Amazon MQ
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable
 ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Authentication failed, see inner exception.)
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090302): The function requested is not supported
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ThrowIfExceptional()
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__64_2(IAsyncResult iar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SslHelper.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<TcpUpgrade>b__0(SslOption opts)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SslHelper.TcpUpgrade(Stream tcpStream, SslOption options)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler..ctor(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Func`2 socketFactory, TimeSpan connectionTimeout, TimeSpan readTimeout, TimeSpan writeTimeout)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.IProtocolExtensions.CreateFrameHandler(IProtocol protocol, AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Func`2 socketFactory, TimeSpan connectionTimeout, TimeSpan readTimeout, TimeSpan writeTimeout)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateFrameHandler(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne[T](IEndpointResolver resolver, Func`2 selector)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne[T](IEndpointResolver resolver, Func`2 selector)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.AutorecoveringConnection.Init(IEndpointResolver endpoints)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String clientProvidedName)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection()
```

After a while digging the error and search and try (for example turn off firewall, add rules for inbound outbound for my application), I could not figure out how to fix this. Anyone could help me to fix this. Thank you very much.

Comment: If it's on Amazon, then might you have forgotten to configure a firewall at the Amazon end?

Comment: All clients are my local machines, not on Amazon. I actually run the code well in several machines with Windows 10 (can create connection, get messages in Queue), but fail in Windows 7.

Comment: I the Win7 the client or the server

Comment: Server is Amazon MQ (RabbitMQ), Win7 is our client @CaiusJard

Comment: OK, so first things first; can you telnet to the RMQ server on port 5672, from the win7 client?

Comment: Yes, I can telnet to RMQ, but the port is 5671, not 5672

Comment: OK, so you know the connection works.. are you certain the credentials are correct (next in the error message is authentication falure)

Comment: I think it is correct, because when I run it on a Windows 10, it worked well. Can connect, get messages from the queue. But error when run on Windows 7, code is the same package and config.

Comment: It's most likely that AWS wants TLS 1.2 and your Windows 7 (which you really shouldn't be using anymore) doesn't support it.

Comment: But I used the same code, same deployment. The one running on Win10 also doesn't use TLS to connect to AWS but still works well. Do you think there's any other reason?

Comment: Windows 10 definitely uses TLS to connect to AWS. The point is that you use a library, which internally uses a .NET API that calls into a Windows API to make the HTTP request to AWS. Different versions and updates of Windows have different capabilities for making HTTP requests.

Comment: Just search "Windows 7 enable TLS 1.2" or something like that, it's probably just that.

Comment: It might be true @CodeCaster, and thank you for the hint. I will try to do it later and will update the result right after I get it. Merry Christmas.

Comment: Hi @CodeCaster, after I enable TLS 1.2 on Win7 and update hotfix kb3140245, I got another error as follows, it seems that still relates to SSL issue

Comment: Error is: Error is: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. 
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacketAsync(Stream transport, AsyncProtocolRequest request)